# Subsection language problem

Tags: fonts, titlesec

I work with LaTeX on Windows XP (MiKTeX 2.8, LEd 0.53) and I use Polish fonts that has several unusual letters like "ą, ż, ć" etc. I work in `book` mode and the problem is that I don't get Polish letters in subsections titles. Everything is fine in normal text, chapters titles and sections titles but it doesn't work with subsections. ;/ Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

the example:

```
\section{Piękny dzień}
```

%%% result:
    2.1 Piękny dzień   <---- it's OK

```
\subsection{Piękny dzień}
```

%%% result:
    2.1.1 Pikny dzie   <---- it's not OK, the special characters disappeared

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Does LaTeX spit out any font-related warnings?

Comment: I get two warnings, but they doesn't concern fonts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This unfortunately isn't quite a MWE yet. Please read the page @lockstep linked you to and supplement your question accordingly.

Comment: Are the "missing" characters in the PDF bookmarks or in the document?

Comment: Closed as too localized because the given code works, required information is missing.